# Euler's first order Error

Tags: numerical-analysis

I was estimating a falling object's position versus time by using a simple first order step function, where

```
for i=2:length(t) % We're using Euler, so we need an initial previous point to start t=t(i);

V=V+dv;

rho_i=    % Calculate our height and then pull rho from data

K=(m/(mg-.5*C_d*A*V^2*rho_i));

 dv=dt/K;



  pos=pos-(V-V_previous)/2*dt;

 V_previous=V;


 velocity_Vector(i)=V;
 pos_Vector(i)=pos;
 end
```

Now I'm wondering, how much will the error be after this thing falls, like many many kilometers?

I know that it's a first order approximation, so there's error...But say I needed to know the bounds on that error.... what would I do to calculate that?

Comment: There are several types of errors you may need to take into account. Roundoff errors are caused by limited-precision arithmetic. Truncation errors come from the fact that Euler's method is only a first-order-in-time approximation to the real trajectory of your falling object. Deriving truncation error bounds for Euler's method is not trivial. Fortunately, it's been done, see, e.g., [here](http://www.math.unl.edu/~gledder1/Math447/EulerError) for the standard estimates (look at Theorem 2). To reduce the truncation errors, you can, e.g., use a more accurate (higher-order) timestepping method.

Comment: Yet another type of error is the model error: in your case, the potential uncertainty in the initial position, value of $\rho$, object mass, air friction coefficient, initial velocity, etc. For your simple problem, you can expect truncation errors to account for the lion's share of the total errors (e.g, round-off errors will be negligible in comparison, particularly if you use double-precision arithmetic).